# Doe Code Effect Rule Engine work persisted data?

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

Hello I stumbled into the Code Effects. The idea behind is very interesting to me, especially the Rule Editor.

Would the engine work with the data that is already saved to a database through entity classes (referred as source objects in Code Effects)? Our system is a data collection system that has a lot of forms. Data in one form could be related to data in more than one other form. For example, we often need to ensure that if an answer to a question in Form 1 is Yes, then Question 3 and 5 on Form 5 must be answered. And there are other types of cross-references between different elements.

Thank you.

John

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dependencies in the Code Effects engine can exist in multiple ways. That's one of the points of having a business rules engine.